# How to calculate SE for a binary measure, given sample size n and known population mean?

Tags: standard-error, binary-data

Lets say there is population of measurements X, and 50% of those X = 1, and the the other  50% = 0.

Therefore, population mean = 0.5

given a random sample of size n, how do you determine the SE of that sample?

Or, in layman's terms, if you flip a coin n times, how far can you expect to deviate from 50% heads and 50% tails?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each outcome may be thought of a bernoulli trial with success probability $p$. A ${\rm Bernoulli}(p)$ random variable has mean $p$ and variance $p(1-p)$. Therefore the average of $n$ independent ${\rm Bernoulli}(p)$ random variables also has mean $p$ and variance $p(1-p)/n$, which is typically estimate by $\hat{p}(1 - \hat{p})/n$. So, in your example the standard error of your mean estimate is $1/\sqrt{4n}$.

Comment: Your calculated standard *error* is what I expected the standard *deviation* to be (i.e., $\sqrt{Var}$). Why is that here we do not need to divide the standard deviation by $\sqrt{n}$ to calculate the standard error?